# Medalha de ouro PHP não traduzida

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

A medalha de ouro PHP está exibindo a seguinte descrição quando exibida no perfil do usuário.

> Earn at least 1000 total score for at least 200 non-community wiki
>   answers in the php tag. These users can single-handedly mark php
>   questions as duplicates and reopen them as needed.

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: The string is translated but [not reviewed yet on transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/$/63722669?q=These%20users%20can%20single-handedly%20mark), I've notified the community team to take care of it.

Comment: @Gabe é você que aprova no transifex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aprovado no Transifex. Só aguardar ir pro ar.